# Equivalent of apply() by row in the tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to insert a new column into a data.frame, which value is TRUE when there is at least one missing value in the row and FALSE otherwise.

For that problem, `apply` is a a perfect use case:

#### EDIT - added example

```
tab <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = c(NA, letters[2:10]), c = c(LETTERS[1:9], NA))

tab$missing <- apply(tab, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

However, I loaded the [strict](https://github.com/hadley/strict) package, and got this error: `apply() coerces X to a matrix so is dangerous to use with data frames.Please use lapply() instead.`

I know that I can safely ignore this error, however, I was wondering if there was a way to code it using one of the tidyverse packages, **in a simple manner**. I tried unsuccessfully with dplyr:

```
tab %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(missing = any(is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `purrr::by_row()`?

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal That was sadly deprecated to [purrrlyr](https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr/)

Comment: btw, you could also avoid the nasty `apply` with `Margin = 1` method and do something Vectorized in the lines of `rowSums(is.na(tab)) > 0`

Comment: Try it this way: `apply(is.na(tab), 1, any)` or `vapply(split(tab, 1:nrow(tab)), f, logical(1))` where `f` is the anonymous function in the question.

Comment: I think the title of this Question is misleading. The title should be along the lines of "How to add a column to a data.frame with Tidyverse".

There have been no answers to what is the Tidyverse equivalent to the apply "by row" function.

Suggested edit queue is currently full

Comment: @HanjoOdendaal Provides actually provides one answer to the title of this question, allthough by_row is now deprecated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid coercing to a matrix, you can use `purrr::pmap`, which iterates across the elements of a list in parallel and passes them to a function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tab <- data_frame(a = 1:10, 
                  b = c(NA, letters[2:10]), 
                  c = c(LETTERS[1:9], NA))

tab %>% mutate(missing = pmap_lgl(., ~any(is.na(c(...)))))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>        a     b     c missing
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>   <lgl>
#>  1     1  <NA>     A    TRUE
#>  2     2     b     B   FALSE
#>  3     3     c     C   FALSE
#>  4     4     d     D   FALSE
#>  5     5     e     E   FALSE
#>  6     6     f     F   FALSE
#>  7     7     g     G   FALSE
#>  8     8     h     H   FALSE
#>  9     9     i     I   FALSE
#> 10    10     j  <NA>    TRUE
```

In the function, `c` is necessary to pull all the parameters passed to the function `...` into a vector, which can be passed to `is.na` and collapsed with `any`. The `*_lgl` suffixed `pmap` simplifies the result to a Boolean vector.

Note that while this avoids coercing to matrix, it will not necessarily be faster than approaches that do, as matrix operations are highly optimized in R. It may make more sense to *explicitly* coerce to a matrix, e.g.

```r
tab %>% mutate(missing = rowSums(is.na(as.matrix(.))) > 0)
```

which returns the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This works for the example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

tab <- data_frame(a = 1:10, 
                  b = c(NA, letters[2:10]), 
                  c = c(LETTERS[1:9], NA))

tab_1 <- tab %>% mutate(missing = ifelse(is.na(b), TRUE, ifelse(is.na(c), TRUE, FALSE)))

> tab_1
    a    b    c missing
1   1 <NA>    A    TRUE
2   2    b    B   FALSE
3   3    c    C   FALSE
4   4    d    D   FALSE
5   5    e    E   FALSE
6   6    f    F   FALSE
7   7    g    G   FALSE
8   8    h    H   FALSE
9   9    i    I   FALSE
10 10    j <NA>    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `complete.cases` function:

```
tab %>% mutate(missing = !complete.cases(.))
```

To remove rows with one or more NAs, use:

```
tab %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```